# При установке некоторых пакетов для Laravel, из github возникает ошибка:

Tags: laravel

При установке некоторых пакетов для Laravel, из github возникает ошибка:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Dotenv\Exception\InvalidFileException: Dotenv
>   values containing spaces must be surrounded by quotes.

Чем вызвана ошибка и как ее исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Проверьте значения переменных в файле .env. скорее всего указаны через пробел: VAR=some data
Если вы всё же используете словосочетания, указывайте их в кавычках
VAR="some data"